# Using numbers form a number

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle, formation-of-numbers

Using 7,8,9 and basic mathematical operations form the number 327600.

Use every digit exactly once.

**Note:**

> Allowed Operations: $+,-,/,*, {}^{\displaystyle\large\hat{}} ,!,\sqrt{}$

Comment: is  raise to ^ allowed ?

Comment: Also please explain "Basic mathematical operations"....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is simple.

> $$ 9!-8!+7! $$

Although I'm not sure that you can really call that operation a "basic mathematical operation". It's kind of in the category of intermediate operations.

Comment: I know it's allowed in the question but I feel ! is just syntactic sugar for using numbers that aren't listed.

Answer (score 2):

Shortest answer I can find using only basic $(+,-,\times,\div)$ operations is

> $$7\times8\times9\times(8\times9\times9+9-7)$$

Comment: I have edited the question.